# How to move programs and registry from one hdd to another?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: Move programs (with registry entries) to a different hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/378480/windows-move-programs-with-registry-entries-to-a-different-hard-drive)

I have just added an SSD drive to my computer and installed windows 8 onto that drive.  Both hard disks are accessible from both operating systems.  How can I copy a program from my Windows 7 operating system on the HDD to Windows 8 on the SSD?  If it matters:  I am trying to move the Adobe Master Collection CS5.5 along with the correct registry and licensing stuff because I no longer have access to the licenses key it is using.